# Modifying column datatypes for select view

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a relatively simple query:

```
SELECT ATTR.*
    FROM NDC_ATTR ATTR
INNER JOIN CONTRACT_NDC_BRG BRG
    ON ATTR.ITEM_ID = BRG.CONTRACT_NUM_VAL AND BRG.CONTRACT_NUM_VAL LIKE '%'+@CONTRACT_NUMBER+'%'
```

The JOIN is causing data type issues:

```
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Testing' to data type int.
```

How can I change the incoming datatypes during the query so I can fix this issue?

Comment: You can't change datatypes but you could potentially cast it as another datatype. What is the datatype of CONTRACT_NUM_VAL?

Comment: 'testing' is not a numeric value and cannot be casted as an integer. Where is that value coming from?

Comment: If I selected PHP it was an accident.

Comment: Yeh sorry about that i'll delete my comment.

Comment: @Sparrow 'Testing' comes from BRG.CONTRACT_NUM_VAL

Comment: What are the column types for 'BRG.CONTRACT_NUM_VAL' and 'ATTR.ITEM_ID'?

Comment: 'BRG.CONTRACT_NUM_VAL' is varchar(500). 'ATTR.ITEM_ID' is an INT. But that's what I'm trying to say. How can I make them compare in the select statement?

Comment: So you are joining on two columns where one is an int and the other is character data. What happens is that it will do an implicit conversion to the higher datatype in precedence order. Int is higher than varchar so it will attempt to cast 'Testing' to an int which will fail. This is often a challenge in EAV type designs which this seems it might be. You can cast/convert as suggested below but there are performance issues with that. It is nonSARGable and forces scans instead of seeks on indexed columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use CAST or CONVERT

**Using CAST:**

```
SELECT ATTR.*
    FROM NDC_ATTR ATTR
INNER JOIN CONTRACT_NDC_BRG BRG
    ON Cast(ATTR.ITEM_ID as varchar(500)) = BRG.CONTRACT_NUM_VAL AND BRG.CONTRACT_NUM_VAL LIKE '%'+@CONTRACT_NUMBER+'%'
```